# Replace all spaces in the key of a property file

Tags: java, regex, ant

I would like to escape all keys that contain spaces in a Java properties file by adding a `\` before them

**Example input**

```
prop with spaces=value with spaces
#comment should not be replaced 
prop_without_spaces=value with spaces 2
```

**Desired output:**

```
prop\ with\ spaces=value with spaces
#comment should not be replaced 
prop_without_spaces=value with spaces 2
```

I know I can replace all spaces with

```
    <replaceregexp byline="true" flags="g" match="\s" replace="\\\\ " file="..."/>
```

But it renders this result

```
prop\ with\ spaces=value\ with\ spaces
#comment\ should\ not\ be\ replaced 
prop_without_spaces=value\ with\ spaces\ 2
```

Or I can do something like this `^(([^=])|(\s))*(=.*)` to match the various groups, but then how do I replace all spaces, e.g. how do I reconstruct the result to include only the non spaces?

In other words, given an input as above, how do I do the following pseudo code, in regex:

- for rows that don't start with a `#`
- for all chars before the first `=` sign
- replace all " " (spaces) with a "\ " (forward slash, space)

Is that possible in RegEx in general, and in Java RegEx in particular? (preferably ANT `replaceregexp` example)

**EDIT**: The solution needs to be a RegEx expression, no code can be involved (unfortunately). I know how to solve this using code :) (thanks for the suggestions though), but I'm trying to go for a RegEx solution first (since I'm using ANT, it will require writing a custom task which I try to avoid).

**EDIT2** Based on the great answers, here are the working ANT versions:

**Using \G**

```
<replaceregexp match="(\\G[^#= ]*) " replace="\1\\\\ " byline="true"... />
```

**Using lookahead**

Escaping comments that have `=` sign in them

```
<replaceregexp match="(\s)(?=.*=)" replace="\\\\ " ... />
```

**Using lookahead + lookbehind**

Not escaping comment lines at all (overkill I think)

```
<replaceregexp match="(?&lt;!#[^=]{0,100})(\s)(?=.*=)" replace="\\\\ " ... />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not necessarily the most efficient but you could use a `match` expression of

```
\s(?=.*=)
```

Which would at least restrict it to matching only spaces to the left of the last equal sign on each line (it wouldn't skip comment lines completely but it would only escape spaces in comments that include an equal sign). This may or may not be sufficient depending on whether any of the *values* contains an equal sign.

Comment: It works great. I can live with escaping comments that have = sign in them, this is a very readable option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't about ant, but if it just runs through a simple `replaceAll`, then you could make use of the `\G` anchor, which ensures that matches are adjacent:

```
"((?:^|\\G)[^#= ]*) "
```

And replace that with `"$1\\ "`. Initially we can ignore the `\\G` alternative. So we simply try to find the start of a line, and then we continue as long as the current character is neither a space, nor starts a comment, nor a value (`[^#= ]*`). And then we match a space. Everything in front of the space is captured into group 1, which we write back with `$1`, then a backslash, then a space.

Now when the matcher tries to match again, in addition to the start of a string, it can also continue where it left off - which is still a position of interest - in any line before a comment or a value.

Of course, make sure to use the `m` modifier to make `^` match the beginning of each line.

[Working demo.](http://fiddle.re/15xpa)

Comment: Hm... interesting, trying it out!

Comment: Oh yes it works! just trying to wrap my head around *how* it works :) but let me do some homework before I ask for clarifications, thanks! + 1000

Comment: Isn't the `^|` actually redundant since `\G` also matches beginning of line?

Comment: Here's an interesting tip: You may remove `^|` because `\G` is initially set to start of input!

Comment: @Jerry as far as I know, `\G` matches the beginning of the *string*, but is not affected by `m`, or is it?

Comment: @EranMedan yeah, just tested it out. removing `^|` is not good because then it will only work on the first line. `\G` does not match the start of subsequent lines.

Comment: @m.buettner thanks! didn't notice it because I used ANT's `byline="true"` flag... p.s. the only reason I accepted the other answer is my own bad RegEx skills (and my colleagues), although your answer is more complete, it will be harder to remember what it does just by looking at it (for me)

Comment: @EranMedan ah, fair enough, if your using it line-wise, then `"(\\G[^#= ]*) "` would indeed be perfectly fine. but sure, go with what's most maintainable for you guys. If you ever feel liking doing something about your RegEx skill, [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) will rocket it skywards ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about doing it with a regex, but if you read each line you could do `string.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ")`, and to avoid the commented lines:

```
if(!string.startsWith("#"))
{
    string = string.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in the qusetion, it will also replace the value it needs to replace all spaces only in the key part...

Comment: See my edit.  Simple question of skipping lines that start with `'#'`

Comment: Thanks, still will replace the value part, (after the = sign). but thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: So do some `String` splicing via substring and concatenation.  This isn't a very difficult problem...

Comment: The requirement is for a pure regex solution, sorry for the confusion, updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

1. Use a FileReader to read each line of the file.
2. For each line split it by `=` into two parts using substring
3. For first part of split apply regular expression
4. Concatenate first park with second part.

Or else you can do it in one line using split.

```
String s = "my name = abc is my name"
System.out.println(s.split("=")[0].replaceAll("\\s", "") + " = " + s.split("=")[1]);
```

Hoping it helps !!

Comment: Thanks! appreciate it, but I'm interested in a pure regex solution :)

Comment: A pure regex solution is, in this situation, only going to make the code more obscure and harder to maintain.

Comment: @StormeHawke you might be correct, but let me see first if there *is* a pure regex solution... since I'm using ANT this will mean writing a custom task, which I try to avoid.

Comment: @EranMedan - Not sure about single regular expression, but you can use split, this may not solve your purpose but another simpler way, see edit.